# Double randomly adds 0.000000000000001

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, ieee-754, floating-point-precision

I have this code:

```
double timeTillTick = 15.0;
private void lower_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timeTillClear > 0)
    {
        timeTillClear -= 0.1;
        clearingIn10SecondsToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Clearing in " + timeTillClear + " seconds.";
    }
    else
    {
        lower.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

lower ticks once every 100 milliseconds. When it:

- Gets to 8
- Gets to 5
- Gets to 1

it increases by `0.000000000000001`. Why?

Comment: We can use `decimal` to keep floating points accurate(called fixed points)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Aniket Thank you! I thought double was a decimal.

Comment: @chipperyman573 `double` is floating point decimal, where as `decimal` is a fixed point decimal.

Comment: @Aniket `decimal` is not fixed-point. `double` is floating-point binary (base-2), `decimal` is floating-point decimal (base-10)

Comment: @CoryNelson oh yeah you're right, buts its still deemed good enough. (Just looked at MSDN and its confirmed), I was wrong. My bad.

Answer (score 5):

Much like `1/3` cannot be represented *exactly* using decimal notation (0.333333...), `0.1` cannot be represented *exactly* as floating point number, which is internally using binary notation (aka IEEE-754). That's why you get that inherent error.